# Ruby on Rails pdf generation

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation

I'm porting desktop application to www with ruby on rails. Desktop application is written in c# and it does generate pretty complecated pdfs. I am wondering is it bad idea to extract classes that generate those pdfs, pack them into command line tool and generate pdfs from rails application by calling this command line program (I can use mono to do this), saving them to the disk and then sending it to browser?

Are there any common known issues that I should be worried about with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating them through a command line call is not bad, and it's what most pdf generation tools are eventually doing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the approach you've outlined, assuming creating your command-line tool is simple enough.

Depending on the requirements of your generated pdf, it might be a good approach to generate an html view and convert it to a pdf. The [pdfkit gem](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/) makes this massively simple:

```
PDFKit.new('http://google.com').to_file("output/google.pdf")
```

All the styling out is done with CSS, and because pdfkit uses webkit, you can use the latest CSS3 styles - rounded corners etc.

Comment: it's pretty complecated, custom paper size etc. so it would be lot easier to just use existing tool.